# Why doesn't Ubuntu have a strategy document?

Tags: project-management

So why is Xubuntu the only one that has a strategy document? Why is there not one for Ubuntu, Ubuntu Server, Kubuntu, etc..? Does this mean that Xubuntu is the only one thinking about these things?

[Xubuntu Strategy Document](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Xubuntu/StrategyDocument)

Answer (score 3):

Though not quite a "strategy" document, the [About Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu) page covers many of the beliefs of Ubuntu, mainly the story, the philosophy, Licensing and Governance, Code of Conduct, Leadership Diversity, and the relationship with Debian and derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has an [agile-driven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) development process: it pushes frequent releases, topic sprints, and short-term, highly-focused goals. This gives Ubuntu the ability to constantly adapt to a changing world; take a look at Unity, which in the space of six months refactored itself from a Netbook UI to a Desktop/Tablet UI.

In the consumer computing industry, players that failed to adopt agile principles have been consistently out-flanked and out-innovated (eg Mozilla, Microsoft) so I don't think that lacking a "five year plan" makes Ubuntu deficient.

I suspect the inner circle at Canonical has rough long-term plans for Ubuntu. It's not public, though.

Comment: Wouldn't that be true of Xubuntu as well? They do have a strategy document at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Xubuntu/StrategyDocument. Just wondering why there isn't one for Ubuntu.